# Making API calls to third party applications via COM: VBScript vs. VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, vbscript, visual-studio-2015, com

I have a program that includes an API for automating tasks within the software.  The vendor uses VBScript for their examples, but I have determined experimentally that I can write code in VB.NET to interact with the API with some caveats:

In VB.NET:

1. I can only create object types defined by the API using late binding (e.g. CreateObject("Type"), thus Intellisense does not work, but calls to the methods exposed by the API *do* work.
2. The application includes a .TLB file that I can reference in my project (Embed Interop Types = False), but attempts to call any methods exposed by that library give an error "This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for this interface with IID{...} failed due to the following error: Error loading type library/DLL)
3. In rare instances, I find API methods that work perfectly when called from VBScript, but throw an exception when called from VB.NET (Invalid Callee).

I'm a bit out of my depth here - but can someone point me in the right direction in terms of either properly referencing/using the type library in VB.NET or explain why in the case of #3, I am having problems even using the late-binding method with VB.NET versus VBScript?

Comment: You have to show code. If you write VBScript code in VB.NET (you only have to add brackets when calling subs) it tends to work.

Comment: I'm sorry,  I didn't mean to imply that I was pasting VBScript directly into my VB.NET project - that isn't the case.  All code in my VB.NET project is written using .NET syntax.

I did do a little more digging and found that I had two versions of the type library given under the same registry key, and that each type I tried to instantiate was referring to a version that did not exist anymore.  That seems to have solved the immediate problem.

Now I just need to figure out how to clean up the registry so that all classes reference the correct type library.

Comment: Open your files in notepad and paste the correct GUID wherever it needs to be. Once you do that, rebuild and the registry should be correct. Crap in the registry is to be expected, but if nothing references it, it doesn't matter.

Comment: The solution was to fully uninstall all versions of the software, then use a tool called CCleaner which removed any references to the type libraries.  After reinstalling, I was able to make the reference to the type library in Visual Studio and I am now able to early-bind those types.

Comment: If the vendor only posts VBScript examples then using the type library is something that just about never gets tested.   The error at 2) is a *threading* problem, happens when you call the api from a worker thread.  That requires a "proxy" so that the call can be made in a thread-safe way, the vendor almost surely did not supply one if VBScript is what they support.  "Invalid callee" is a very obscure problem, means "we don't actually support CreateObject".  Yikes.  Having a good working relationship with this vendor is rather crucial, you'll need their help.

Comment: That makes perfect sense - virtually everything that happens in my code is done using the background worker.  After resolving the registry issues, and redefining my late-bound objects in the most affected functions as typed, I no longer received either of those two errors.  I do receive warnings now about how a number of arguments in the library interfaces "cannot be marshaled by the runtime marshaler".  I have some reading to do to understand that, but it doesn't appear to have an adverse effect on the program's behavior.